# compare current node siblings with preceding node siblings

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to compare the `AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure` and `AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure` of the Monday with rest of the days.

- If the start and end time are equal for monday and tuesday I need to display days as "Mon-Tue"
- If all weekday timings are same then "Mon-Fri"
- If it is not matched I want to display the `DaysOfWeek` and `AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure` and `AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure`.

XML:

```
<HoursOfOperation>
    <HoursTypeCode>Sales</HoursTypeCode>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Monday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">510</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1140</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Tuesday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">510</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1140</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Wednesday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">510</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1140</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Thursday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">510</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1140</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Friday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">510</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1140</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Saturday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">600</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1080</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Sunday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">660</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1080</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
</HoursOfOperation>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="DaysOfWeek">  
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($StartTime = AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure) and ($EndTime = AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure)">                
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="pnode"><xsl:value-of select="(preceding-sibling::*[DayOfWeekCode])[last()]" /></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pnode" />                
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Now this is printing

> Friday 510 1140 Saturday 600 1080

I just want to display Friday Saturday. how i need to modify preceding-sibling to get only Friday and Saturday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you output a result whenever the test is true; you should wait until the test fails and only then close the string with the *preceding* day's name.

There's probably a better method to do this, but I am not sure I understand the logic: will you be repeating this test for each day < Sunday? What if the matches are {Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Sunday} and {Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday}?

---

**ADDENDUM**:

Assuming we want to group days by their availability times, regardless of being consecutive or not, the following stylesheet uses the Muenchian grouping method to do just that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="similarDays" 
         match="DaysOfWeek" 
         use="concat(AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure, '|', AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<table>
<xsl:for-each select="HoursOfOperation/DaysOfWeek[count(. | key('similarDays', concat(AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure, '|', AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure))[1]) = 1]">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('similarDays', concat(AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure, '|', AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure))">
                <xsl:value-of select="DayOfWeekCode"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            <xsl:call-template name="minutes2time">
                <xsl:with-param name="minutes" select="AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="minutes2time">
                <xsl:with-param name="minutes" select="AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="minutes2time">
    <xsl:param name="minutes"/>
    <xsl:param name="h" select="floor($minutes div 60)"/>
    <xsl:param name="m" select="$minutes mod 60"/>
    <xsl:param name="pad" select="substring('0', 1, $m &lt; 10)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($h, ':', $pad, $m)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your original example, this would generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">8:30 - 19:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">10:00 - 18:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sunday</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">11:00 - 18:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

that renders as:

```
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday     8:30 - 19:00
Saturday                                        10:00 - 18:00
Sunday                                          11:00 - 18:00
```

Applied to a modified input in the form of:

```
<HoursOfOperation>
    <HoursTypeCode>Sales</HoursTypeCode>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Monday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">510</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1140</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Tuesday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">510</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1140</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Wednesday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">660</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1080</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Thursday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">510</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1140</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Friday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">600</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1200</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Saturday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">660</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1080</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
        <DayOfWeekCode>Sunday</DayOfWeekCode>
        <AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">660</AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure>
        <AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure unitCode="minute">1080</AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure>
    </DaysOfWeek>
</HoursOfOperation>
```

the (rendered) output would be:

```
Monday, Tuesday, Thursday       8:30 - 19:00
Wednesday, Saturday, Sunday    11:00 - 18:00
Friday                         10:00 - 20:00
```

Comment: if the matches are{Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Sunday} and {Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday} i don't know how to do that.for now i am trying to capture the preceding node name in the otherwise loop but i am getting all node values(node name,start time,end time).

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your comment. My question was (and still is) what is the ultimate goal here?

Comment: if you notice my XML from Monday to Friday AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure and AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure are same and Saturday,Sunday timings are different 
so i want to display

    Mon-Fri AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure
    Sat AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure
    Sun AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure

Comment: @user2962780 I am still not quite clear on what is a pattern here and what is a mere coincidence. For now, I have added a general method to group ANY days with matching availability times; if the groups are known in advance (e.g. Mon - Fri are *always* the same) then this can be simpler. If you need to collapse any group of consecutive days (e.g Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday into Tue - Thu) then this needs to be more complex - perhaps even much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand about your question, you would want to display `DayofWeekCode` if `$StartTime` and `$EndTime` did not match the current `AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure` and `AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure` in the loop. The code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="StartTime" select="/HoursOfOperation/DaysOfWeek[1]/AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure[1]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="EndTime" select="/HoursOfOperation/DaysOfWeek[1]/AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure[1]"/>
    <xsl:template match="HoursOfOperation">
        <xsl:for-each select="DaysOfWeek">  
            <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="($StartTime != AvailabilityStartTimeMeasure) and ($EndTime != AvailabilityEndTimeMeasure)">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="position()!=last()">
                                <xsl:value-of select="DayOfWeekCode"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="DayOfWeekCode"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs

```
Saturday Sunday
```

because they are the ones that do not match `$StartTime` and `$EndTime`

Comment: Final output i want to print is

Mon-Fri 8:30am - 7pm
Sat 10am - 6pm
Sun 11am - 6pm
 i am able to do the time conversions but the only issue is i am not able to group the days that have same timings.